# Pop out a react component into a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering if it is possible to pop out a React component that has a whole Redux Store etc. into a new window with an iframe.

This is probably not possible to do but I wanted to see if anyone knew a way to achieve this?

The reason I want to popout the React component/application to a new window is so that I can keep the React App going while redirecting the user to another URL/Domain.

My React App/Component gets appended to a handlebars template using a `<script>` tag and a CDN to our bundled React App.

Comment: You could store the state of the app either locally using `localStorage`, or send it to the server. Then load the app normally in the iFrame and if it detects the stored version, load that it to continue from where it left off

Comment: I don't think storing the state into local storage would solve everything. The reason is my React App/Component that is on the Zendesk template is a Chat Widget and I am using a SDK API to initialize a Chat. I don't think I can simply save this Chat object provided by the SDK into storage and read it from an iframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [React Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to open a new window and maintain it under React tree.

It's a semi-long post so check out this post.
[Using a React 16 Portal to do something cool](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202)

You can open a new window, do what you need to do, and forward the user to a different URL, which won't affect your original window.

Comment: When you say forward the user to a different URL, do you mean to open that URL in another tab/window? To be clear of what I need to do is, my React application that sits in the handlebars template is a Chat Widget. When a user clicks on a button at a certain point in the handlebars template, I want to redirect the user to another URL/domain in the same tab that had the handlebars page and just pop out the React Chat Widget Application/Component

Comment: I forgot to mention I am not using React 16

Comment: Link does not longer work, but with a simple search inside hackernoon with a phrase like "react portal" shows you many interesting articles about it.

Comment: @JoséAlvarez: link is fixed now. Ty for pointing it out