# Popup a part of a react app into a new window

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to be able to load it in a new window. I've consulted the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52597250/pop-out-a-react-component-into-a-new-window) and the related article and was able to get the dom tree to render in a portal, but not a whole lot more.

1. `onMouseEnter` for example doesn't fire in the new window.
2. I have `react-tippy` which seems to do some automagical stuff globally, this doesn't seem to work / causes issues on the new window
3. I have a webgl canvas that's being managed by three.js. It's also somewhat automagical as it's not managed by react, but just sits in the `<body>` and covers the whole window. React manages "views" into this canvas.

I'm struggling to understand how this should be handled. For example this is how my `ReactDOM.render` call looks like:

```
const webglViewManager = new WebGLViewManager()
const threeRenderer = new ThreeRenderer(webglViewManager)

render(
  <ThreeContext.Provider value={{ webglViewManager, threeRenderer }}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactApp store={store} />
    </Provider>
  </ThreeContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

I've tried to pass a document (either the one i'm on, or the one from the popup window) to my three context to have it append a canvas there but that didn't quite seem to work. Overall i'm too intimidated to even experiment with this since i feel i'm reasoning about this all the wrong way.

How much mileage can i get with these relatively complex systems (the way tippy mounts, three.js) and portals spread over multiple windows? Would it make more sense to just to make a separate "app" to load into the other window, if so how would that be achieved? Load the same entry point but route to this view, a whole other app...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had success with spawning a child window via `window.open`. What i found useful was to create a window context ie:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react'

export const WindowContext = createContext<Window | null>(null as any)
export const useWindowContext = () => useContext(WindowContext)
```

And put this provider around my new windows. I had to change all my portals that mount to mount to the body of the new window but so far this seems to be working fine.

Comment: I have a similar situation, I need to open a new window and share context with it. I would appreciate if you could share a code example.